# FFmpeg cuts video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to add an image to the start of a video. I don't want it to overwrite the video, I asked about it and got this answer:

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -loop 1 -t 3 -i image.jpg -i inputvideo.mxf -f lavfi -t 3 -i aevalsrc=0 -filter_complex "[0:v] [2:a] [1:v] [1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict -2 -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

It does what I asked for but on two of the videos I'm using it on, it cuts the video with 14/15 seconds. It works on a 300mb and 200mb video but it cuts on a 65/188mb video. Any ideas what is causing this? The fps from ffprobe is 29.97 on all the videos so I set it to 30 as you can see.
All the videos are in .mxf format, I'm adding the same image to all of them.

This is the ffmpeg output from the above command.

```
ffmpeg version N-74751-gb54e03c Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.3 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 59.100 / 56. 59.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.100 /  5. 40.100
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, image2, from 'C:/image.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 9027 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[mxf @ 0000000002fad680] broken or empty index
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #1.1 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #1.2 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #1.3 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #1.4 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #1.5 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #1.6 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #1.7 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #1.8 : mono
Input #1, mxf, from 'C:/video.mxf':
  Metadata:
    uid             : 8206ba85-3954-2f4a-9d3c-c4e8d5ba793a
    generation_uid  : de90d87a-f4a7-944c-b6c1-368903cb7a3f
    company_name    : Rhozet
    product_name    : Carbon
    product_version : 1.00
    product_uid     : 060e2b34-0401-0101-0e00-000000000000
    modification_date: 2015-10-30 15:45:05
    material_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D33130000009BC9C7D36B3F43438EAECC12C87EB630
    timecode        : 00:00:00:00
  Duration: 00:00:42.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 36660 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: mpeg2video (4:2:2), yuv422p(tv), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 50000 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 29.97 tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D3313000000B70F9172F67EE340AE91E11FC1BA4B0B
    Stream #1:1: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D3313000000B70F9172F67EE340AE91E11FC1BA4B0B
    Stream #1:2: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D3313000000B70F9172F67EE340AE91E11FC1BA4B0B
    Stream #1:3: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D3313000000B70F9172F67EE340AE91E11FC1BA4B0B
    Stream #1:4: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D3313000000B70F9172F67EE340AE91E11FC1BA4B0B
    Stream #1:5: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D3313000000B70F9172F67EE340AE91E11FC1BA4B0B
    Stream #1:6: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D3313000000B70F9172F67EE340AE91E11FC1BA4B0B
    Stream #1:7: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D3313000000B70F9172F67EE340AE91E11FC1BA4B0B
    Stream #1:8: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D3313000000B70F9172F67EE340AE91E11FC1BA4B0B
    Stream #1:9: Data: none
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D3313000000B70F9172F67EE340AE91E11FC1BA4B0B
      data_type       : vbi_vanc_smpte_436M
Input #2, lavfi, from 'aevalsrc=0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #2:0: Audio: pcm_f64le, 44100 Hz, mono, dbl, 2822 kb/s
[swscaler @ 0000000004e71040] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
No pixel format specified, yuv422p for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
[libx264 @ 0000000004e22020] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0000000004e22020] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0000000004e22020] profile High 4:2:2, level 4.0, 4:2:2 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0000000004e22020] 264 - core 148 r2597 e86f3a1 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=1 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/COMBO_2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv422p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.59.100 libx264
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.59.100 aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (mjpeg) -> concat:in0:v0
  Stream #1:0 (mpeg2video) -> concat:in1:v0
  Stream #1:1 (pcm_s24le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #2:0 (pcm_f64le) -> concat:in0:a0
  concat:out:v0 -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  concat:out:a0 -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   32 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.02 bitrate=   0.4kbits/s    frame=   43 fps= 41 q=29.0 size=       9kB time=00:00:01.38 bitrate=  54.8kbits/s    frame=   57 fps= 36 q=29.0 size=      11kB time=00:00:01.83 bitrate=  47.7kbits/s    frame=   70 fps= 34 q=29.0 size=      12kB time=00:00:02.28 bitrate=  42.2kbits/s    frame=   81 fps= 31 q=29.0 size=      13kB time=00:00:02.64 bitrate=  39.2kbits/s    frame=   94 fps= 31 q=29.0 size=      14kB time=00:00:03.07 bitrate=  36.6kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  111 fps= 31 q=29.0 size=      15kB time=00:00:03.64 bitrate=  34.0kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  129 fps= 31 q=29.0 size=      17kB time=00:00:04.24 bitrate=  32.1kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  147 fps= 32 q=29.0 size=      18kB time=00:00:04.84 bitrate=  30.6kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  166 fps= 32 q=29.0 size=      20kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate=  29.2kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  183 fps= 32 q=29.0 size=      21kB time=00:00:06.05 bitrate=  28.1kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  202 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=      22kB time=00:00:06.67 bitrate=  27.3kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  219 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=      24kB time=00:00:07.25 bitrate=  26.6kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  237 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=      25kB time=00:00:07.85 bitrate=  26.0kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  255 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=      26kB time=00:00:08.44 bitrate=  25.4kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  274 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=      28kB time=00:00:09.08 bitrate=  24.9kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  289 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=      90kB time=00:00:09.57 bitrate=  76.6kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  305 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=      91kB time=00:00:10.11 bitrate=  73.6kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  320 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=      92kB time=00:00:10.62 bitrate=  71.1kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  336 fps= 32 q=29.0 size=      93kB time=00:00:11.15 bitrate=  68.6kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  352 fps= 32 q=29.0 size=      95kB time=00:00:11.69 bitrate=  66.5kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  368 fps= 32 q=29.0 size=      96kB time=00:00:12.22 bitrate=  64.5kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  384 fps= 32 q=29.0 size=      98kB time=00:00:12.75 bitrate=  62.6kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  399 fps= 32 q=29.0 size=      99kB time=00:00:13.24 bitrate=  61.1kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  414 fps= 32 q=29.0 size=     100kB time=00:00:13.76 bitrate=  59.6kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  429 fps= 32 q=29.0 size=     101kB time=00:00:14.25 bitrate=  58.2kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  447 fps= 32 q=29.0 size=     103kB time=00:00:14.84 bitrate=  56.8kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  460 fps= 32 q=29.0 size=     104kB time=00:00:15.29 bitrate=  55.7kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  472 fps= 31 q=29.0 size=     105kB time=00:00:15.70 bitrate=  54.7kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  484 fps= 31 q=29.0 size=     106kB time=00:00:16.08 bitrate=  53.9kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  493 fps= 30 q=26.0 size=     330kB time=00:00:16.38 bitrate= 164.8kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  496 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=     391kB time=00:00:16.49 bitrate= 194.0kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  498 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=     447kB time=00:00:16.55 bitrate= 221.4kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  502 fps= 28 q=29.0 size=     517kB time=00:00:16.70 bitrate= 253.7kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  506 fps= 27 q=29.0 size=     595kB time=00:00:16.83 bitrate= 289.7kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  510 fps= 26 q=29.0 size=     666kB time=00:00:16.96 bitrate= 321.8kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  514 fps= 25 q=29.0 size=     729kB time=00:00:17.08 bitrate= 349.7kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  518 fps= 24 q=29.0 size=     792kB time=00:00:17.23 bitrate= 376.3kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  522 fps= 23 q=29.0 size=     870kB time=00:00:17.36 bitrate= 410.3kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  525 fps= 23 q=29.0 size=     935kB time=00:00:17.45 bitrate= 438.8kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  529 fps= 22 q=29.0 size=     997kB time=00:00:17.60 bitrate= 463.9kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  533 fps= 22 q=29.0 size=    1053kB time=00:00:17.72 bitrate= 486.5kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  537 fps= 21 q=29.0 size=    1125kB time=00:00:17.85 bitrate= 516.1kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  541 fps= 21 q=29.0 size=    1189kB time=00:00:18.00 bitrate= 540.8kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  545 fps= 20 q=29.0 size=    1242kB time=00:00:18.13 bitrate= 561.3kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  549 fps= 20 q=29.0 size=    1297kB time=00:00:18.26 bitrate= 581.6kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  553 fps= 19 q=29.0 size=    1347kB time=00:00:18.38 bitrate= 599.9kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  557 fps= 19 q=29.0 size=    1380kB time=00:00:18.53 bitrate= 609.9kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  560 fps= 19 q=29.0 size=    1574kB time=00:00:18.62 bitrate= 692.2kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  564 fps= 18 q=29.0 size=    1628kB time=00:00:18.75 bitrate= 711.1kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  568 fps= 18 q=29.0 size=    1692kB time=00:00:18.90 bitrate= 733.1kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  571 fps= 18 q=29.0 size=    1750kB time=00:00:18.98 bitrate= 754.9kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  574 fps= 17 q=29.0 size=    1793kB time=00:00:19.09 bitrate= 769.5kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  578 fps= 17 q=29.0 size=    1848kB time=00:00:19.22 bitrate= 787.7kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  582 fps= 17 q=29.0 size=    1907kB time=00:00:19.37 bitrate= 806.6kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  585 fps= 17 q=29.0 size=    1961kB time=00:00:19.45 bitrate= 825.6kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  588 fps= 16 q=29.0 size=    2005kB time=00:00:19.56 bitrate= 839.5kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    frame=  593 fps= 16 q=29.0 size=    2066kB time=00:00:19.69 bitrate= 859.7kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  596 fps= 16 q=29.0 size=    2103kB time=00:00:19.79 bitrate= 870.0kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  599 fps= 16 q=29.0 size=    2146kB time=00:00:19.90 bitrate= 883.4kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  601 fps= 16 q=29.0 size=    2211kB time=00:00:19.96 bitrate= 906.9kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  605 fps= 15 q=29.0 size=    2267kB time=00:00:20.09 bitrate= 924.2kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  608 fps= 15 q=29.0 size=    2308kB time=00:00:20.20 bitrate= 935.7kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  611 fps= 15 q=29.0 size=    2347kB time=00:00:20.28 bitrate= 947.9kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  613 fps= 15 q=29.0 size=    2382kB time=00:00:20.37 bitrate= 957.8kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  616 fps= 15 q=29.0 size=    2423kB time=00:00:20.45 bitrate= 970.3kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  620 fps= 15 q=26.0 size=    2699kB time=00:00:20.60 bitrate=1073.1kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  624 fps= 15 q=29.0 size=    2734kB time=00:00:20.73 bitrate=1080.0kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  627 fps= 14 q=29.0 size=    2766kB time=00:00:20.82 bitrate=1088.3kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  629 fps= 14 q=29.0 size=    2813kB time=00:00:20.90 bitrate=1102.3kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  631 fps= 14 q=29.0 size=    2861kB time=00:00:20.97 bitrate=1117.6kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  635 fps= 14 q=29.0 size=    2900kB time=00:00:21.09 bitrate=1125.9kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  639 fps= 14 q=29.0 size=    2941kB time=00:00:21.22 bitrate=1135.2kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  643 fps= 14 q=29.0 size=    2992kB time=00:00:21.35 bitrate=1147.9kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  646 fps= 14 q=29.0 size=    3037kB time=00:00:21.46 bitrate=1159.3kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  649 fps= 14 q=29.0 size=    3077kB time=00:00:21.56 bitrate=1168.9kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  652 fps= 13 q=29.0 size=    3137kB time=00:00:21.67 bitrate=1185.5kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  655 fps= 13 q=29.0 size=    3176kB time=00:00:21.76 bitrate=1195.7kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  658 fps= 13 q=29.0 size=    3239kB time=00:00:21.86 bitrate=1213.5kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  660 fps= 13 q=29.0 size=    3283kB time=00:00:21.93 bitrate=1226.2kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  663 fps= 13 q=29.0 size=    3343kB time=00:00:22.03 bitrate=1242.9kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  665 fps= 13 q=29.0 size=    3388kB time=00:00:22.10 bitrate=1255.8kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  668 fps= 13 q=29.0 size=    3447kB time=00:00:22.20 bitrate=1271.3kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  670 fps= 13 q=29.0 size=    3493kB time=00:00:22.27 bitrate=1284.7kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  673 fps= 13 q=29.0 size=    3549kB time=00:00:22.35 bitrate=1300.6kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  675 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    3617kB time=00:00:22.44 bitrate=1320.3kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  678 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    3678kB time=00:00:22.52 bitrate=1337.5kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  681 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    3743kB time=00:00:22.63 bitrate=1354.5kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  684 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    3777kB time=00:00:22.74 bitrate=1360.7kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  687 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    3827kB time=00:00:22.82 bitrate=1373.6kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  689 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    3880kB time=00:00:22.89 bitrate=1388.5kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  692 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    3911kB time=00:00:22.99 bitrate=1393.1kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  695 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    3970kB time=00:00:23.10 bitrate=1407.5kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  698 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    4001kB time=00:00:23.21 bitrate=1412.1kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  701 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    4043kB time=00:00:23.29 bitrate=1421.9kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  704 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    4092kB time=00:00:23.40 bitrate=1432.3kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  707 fps= 12 q=29.0 size=    4125kB time=00:00:23.50 bitrate=1437.3kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  710 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=    4150kB time=00:00:23.59 bitrate=1441.0kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  714 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=    4180kB time=00:00:23.74 bitrate=1442.3kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  718 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=    4209kB time=00:00:23.87 bitrate=1444.4kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  720 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=    4250kB time=00:00:23.93 bitrate=1454.6kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  724 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=    4285kB time=00:00:24.06 bitrate=1458.9kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  728 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=    4316kB time=00:00:24.19 bitrate=1461.5kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  732 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=    4342kB time=00:00:24.34 bitrate=1461.4kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  735 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=    4374kB time=00:00:24.42 bitrate=1466.9kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  739 fps= 11 q=26.0 size=    4506kB time=00:00:24.57 bitrate=1501.9kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  743 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=    4573kB time=00:00:24.70 bitrate=1516.5kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  746 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=    4628kB time=00:00:24.81 bitrate=1528.1kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  749 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=    4685kB time=00:00:24.89 bitrate=1541.6kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  752 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=    4731kB time=00:00:25.00 bitrate=1550.1kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  755 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=    4815kB time=00:00:25.10 bitrate=1570.8kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  758 fps= 11 q=29.0 size=    4858kB time=00:00:25.19 bitrate=1579.6kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  761 fps= 10 q=29.0 size=    4909kB time=00:00:25.30 bitrate=1589.4kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  764 fps= 10 q=29.0 size=    4969kB time=00:00:25.40 bitrate=1602.1kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  767 fps= 10 q=29.0 size=    4999kB time=00:00:25.49 bitrate=1606.5kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  770 fps= 10 q=29.0 size=    5064kB time=00:00:25.60 bitrate=1620.5kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  773 fps= 10 q=29.0 size=    5096kB time=00:00:25.70 bitrate=1623.9kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  776 fps= 10 q=29.0 size=    5136kB time=00:00:25.81 bitrate=1629.8kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  779 fps= 10 q=29.0 size=    5192kB time=00:00:25.89 bitrate=1642.3kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  782 fps= 10 q=29.0 size=    5230kB time=00:00:26.00 bitrate=1647.6kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  785 fps= 10 q=29.0 size=    5304kB time=00:00:26.11 bitrate=1663.9kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  788 fps= 10 q=29.0 size=    5347kB time=00:00:26.19 bitrate=1672.0kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  791 fps= 10 q=29.0 size=    5388kB time=00:00:26.30 bitrate=1678.0kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  794 fps=9.9 q=29.0 size=    5447kB time=00:00:26.41 bitrate=1689.6kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  796 fps=9.9 q=29.0 size=    5491kB time=00:00:26.47 bitrate=1699.2kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  799 fps=9.8 q=29.0 size=    5529kB time=00:00:26.56 bitrate=1705.3kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  801 fps=9.8 q=29.0 size=    5572kB time=00:00:26.64 bitrate=1713.1kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  804 fps=9.8 q=29.0 size=    5616kB time=00:00:26.73 bitrate=1721.1kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  806 fps=9.7 q=29.0 size=    5663kB time=00:00:26.79 bitrate=1731.5kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  809 fps=9.7 q=29.0 size=    5720kB time=00:00:26.90 bitrate=1742.0kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  812 fps=9.7 q=29.0 size=    5763kB time=00:00:27.00 bitrate=1747.9kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  815 fps=9.6 q=29.0 size=    5828kB time=00:00:27.11 bitrate=1760.9kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  818 fps=9.6 q=29.0 size=    5865kB time=00:00:27.20 bitrate=1766.3kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  821 fps=9.5 q=29.0 size=    5908kB time=00:00:27.30 bitrate=1772.5kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  824 fps=9.5 q=29.0 size=    5954kB time=00:00:27.41 bitrate=1779.3kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  827 fps=9.5 q=29.0 size=    5989kB time=00:00:27.49 bitrate=1784.2kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  831 fps=9.5 q=29.0 size=    6096kB time=00:00:27.64 bitrate=1806.3kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  834 fps=9.4 q=29.0 size=    6125kB time=00:00:27.73 bitrate=1809.2kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  837 fps=9.4 q=29.0 size=    6165kB time=00:00:27.84 bitrate=1814.1kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  840 fps=9.4 q=29.0 size=    6207kB time=00:00:27.94 bitrate=1819.5kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  844 fps=9.3 q=29.0 size=    6244kB time=00:00:28.07 bitrate=1822.0kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  847 fps=9.3 q=29.0 size=    6275kB time=00:00:28.18 bitrate=1824.0kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  850 fps=9.3 q=29.0 size=    6313kB time=00:00:28.26 bitrate=1829.7kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  853 fps=9.3 q=29.0 size=    6346kB time=00:00:28.37 bitrate=1832.1kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    frame=  856 fps=9.2 q=29.0 size=    6376kB time=00:00:28.48 bitrate=1834.1kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    [mpeg2video @ 000000000307dc00] ac-tex damaged at 11 49
[mpeg2video @ 000000000307dc00] Warning MVs not available
[mpeg2video @ 000000000307dc00] concealing 2280 DC, 2280 AC, 2280 MV errors in I frame
frame=  858 fps=8.7 q=29.0 Lsize=    6836kB time=00:00:28.54 bitrate=1961.8kbits/s dup=2 drop=0    
video:6586kB audio:217kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.465456%
[libx264 @ 0000000004e22020] frame I:9     Avg QP:18.65  size:110948
[libx264 @ 0000000004e22020] frame P:303   Avg QP:18.65  size: 14758
[libx264 @ 0000000004e22020] frame B:546   Avg QP:18.22  size:  2333
[libx264 @ 0000000004e22020] consecutive B-frames: 10.1% 13.5%  4.5% 71.8%
[libx264 @ 0000000004e22020] mb I  I16..4: 28.0% 66.3%  5.7%
[libx264 @ 0000000004e22020] mb P  I16..4:  2.0%  1.8%  0.1%  P16..4: 29.7%  3.9%  5.3%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:57.2%
[libx264 @ 0000000004e22020] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.1%  0.0%  B16..8: 12.9%  0.2%  0.0%  direct: 0.9%  skip:85.9%  L0:42.6% L1:55.7% BI: 1.7%
[libx264 @ 0000000004e22020] 8x8 transform intra:54.9% inter:92.1%
[libx264 @ 0000000004e22020] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 32.1% 73.0% 27.0% inter: 3.6% 16.4% 1.1%
[libx264 @ 0000000004e22020] i16 v,h,dc,p: 41% 27%  8% 24%
[libx264 @ 0000000004e22020] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 31% 18% 33%  2%  3%  4%  3%  3%  3%
[libx264 @ 0000000004e22020] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 35% 19% 11%  5%  7%  8%  5%  6%  4%
[libx264 @ 0000000004e22020] i8c dc,h,v,p: 53% 16% 24%  6%
[libx264 @ 0000000004e22020] Weighted P-Frames: Y:4.6% UV:1.0%
[libx264 @ 0000000004e22020] ref P L0: 57.4% 11.4% 21.6%  9.4%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 0000000004e22020] ref B L0: 87.5% 11.2%  1.3%
[libx264 @ 0000000004e22020] ref B L1: 95.7%  4.3%
[libx264 @ 0000000004e22020] kb/s:1886.37
```

This is the ffprobe output:

```
ffprobe version N-74751-gb54e03c Copyright (c) 2007-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.3 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 59.100 / 56. 59.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.100 /  5. 40.100
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[mxf @ 000000000310b8a0] broken or empty index
Input #0, mxf, from 'C:/video.mxf':
  Metadata:
    uid             : 8206ba85-3954-2f4a-9d3c-c4e8d5ba793a
    generation_uid  : de90d87a-f4a7-944c-b6c1-368903cb7a3f
    company_name    : Rhozet
    product_name    : Carbon
    product_version : 1.00
    product_uid     : 060e2b34-0401-0101-0e00-000000000000
    modification_date: 2015-10-30 15:45:05
    material_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D33130000009BC9C7D36B3F43438EAECC12C87EB630
    timecode        : 00:00:00:00
  Duration: 00:00:42.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 36660 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg2video (4:2:2), yuv422p(tv), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 50000 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 29.97 tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D3313000000B70F9172F67EE340AE91E11FC1BA4B0B
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D3313000000B70F9172F67EE340AE91E11FC1BA4B0B
    Stream #0:2: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D3313000000B70F9172F67EE340AE91E11FC1BA4B0B
    Stream #0:3: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D3313000000B70F9172F67EE340AE91E11FC1BA4B0B
    Stream #0:4: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D3313000000B70F9172F67EE340AE91E11FC1BA4B0B
    Stream #0:5: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D3313000000B70F9172F67EE340AE91E11FC1BA4B0B
    Stream #0:6: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D3313000000B70F9172F67EE340AE91E11FC1BA4B0B
    Stream #0:7: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D3313000000B70F9172F67EE340AE91E11FC1BA4B0B
    Stream #0:8: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D3313000000B70F9172F67EE340AE91E11FC1BA4B0B
    Stream #0:9: Data: none
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D3313000000B70F9172F67EE340AE91E11FC1BA4B0B
      data_type       : vbi_vanc_smpte_436M
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 9
```

Comment: Can you link to the video with which the problem occurs? Or at least paste the entire ffprobe and also the ffmpeg output when you cut it?

Answer (score 1):

The ff* tools report this for the errant input video:

```
[mxf @ 0000000002fad680] broken or empty index
```

Try copying into a new container.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mxf -c copy output.mxf
```

and then run the image prefix command.

Comment: I've had to do this for other file types.